# Weird equal sign "=" inserts in <textarea> value when uploading file via POST using blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler on Google App Engine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, encode

Can only reproduce this issue on Google App Engine Server, not on my development server. 
Only when I copy-paste a part of web page to the `<textarea>`.

I searched Google App Engine forum and found two related posts, but still didn't figure it out. Can somebody give me more hint? Thanks!

Here is my code:

HTML

```
< form method = "post" action = "{% if action %}{{ action }}{% endif %}" enctype = "multipart/form-data" accept - charset = "UTF-8" >
< textarea name = "textbox" id = "textbox" rows = "3" cols = "50" wrap = "soft" >
```

Python

```
t1 = self.request.get("textbox")
t2 = self.request.POST["textbox"]
logging.info("request get: %s, %s" % (t1, t2))
```

Related Posts:
http://code.google.com/appengine/forum/python-forum.html?place=topic%2Fgoogle-appengine-python%2FOYfn9tXncUk%2Fdiscussion

http://code.google.com/appengine/forum/python-forum.html?place=topic%2Fgoogle-appengine-python%2FCsSrUmb7N4E%2Fdiscussion

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML code of the textarea when the weird symbol appears?

Comment: This is still happening 18 months later.  Wish Google would fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to a hint on Google App Engine Forums from user Djidjadji I found that `quopri.decodestring()` helps me out! Here is the code I used. Hope it can save other dispirited programmers' time :)

```
tMessage = self.request.get("tMessage")

tMessage = quopri.decodestring(tMessage)

tMessage = " ".join(tMessage.split()) #Remove all whitespace

logging.info("tMessage: %s" % tMessage)
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the textarea has non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug in the outdated WebOb library](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749) of Google App Engine.

Just add add this newer version of WebOb in your app.yaml file.

```
libraries:
- name: webob
  version: "1.2.3"
```

The proposed `quopri` fix by Josh Caswell is only half the rent. It doesn't work with non-ascii characted.